# There is no sizeof operator in java. How can I find size of an object in java?

Tags: java

> **Possible Duplicates:**
>   [Programatically calculate memory occupied by a Java Object including objects it references](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/757300/programatically-calculate-memory-occupied-by-a-java-object-including-objects-it-r)
>   [In Java, what is the best way to determine the size of an object?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52353/in-java-what-is-the-best-way-to-determine-the-size-of-an-object)

Hi

There is no sizeof operator in java ..
But how can i know the size of an object in java?
Thanks

Comment: Duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/757300/programatically-calculate-memory-occupied-by-a-java-object-including-objects-it-r

Answer (score 1):

You may serialize the object to a byte array output stream.

That won't give you the exact size of the object because it will skip the transient data, but at least will give you a good idea of how big your objects are.

Answer (score 1):

You can't. The internal representation is JVM-specific. If you want an empirical estimate for your JVM them you can try this: 1) turn on verbose garbage collector output (see JVM flags) 2) in your program invoke a full GC 3) create a lot of copies of the same object 4) invoke a full GC again 5) compare the heap size after steps 2 and 4 and divide by the number of objects

Answer (score 1):

There is no portable *direct* way, and the answer is different between JVMs (since the spec is silent on implementation details).

Here's [an excellent article](http://www.javaspecialists.eu/archive/Issue029.html) showing one approach.

Answer (score 0):

My first question would be what are you doing that requires sizeof?  There are no pointers for you to manipulate, so you really have no need to know.

SO Duplicate?: [In Java, what is the best way to determine the size of an object?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52353/in-java-what-is-the-best-way-to-determine-the-size-of-an-object)